# Complicated adjoint functor diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

How can I make two diagrams like in the following picture? Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome! With `tikz-cd` this is rather straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[r,shift left=0.75ex] \arrow[r,draw=none,"\sim" marking]& 
    B \arrow[l,shift left=0.75ex]\arrow[r,shift left=0.75ex]
    \arrow[r,,draw=none,"\scriptstyle\perp" marking]& 
    C \arrow[l,shift left=0.75ex]\\
 C \arrow[r,"\scriptstyle\perp" {inner sep=0.1ex,rotate=180},
    "\scriptstyle\perp"' {inner sep=0.1ex,rotate=180}] \arrow[r,shift left=1.5ex] & 
    D \arrow[l,shift left=1.5ex] & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with even smaller `\perp` symbols to move the arrows closer to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[r,shift left=0.4ex] \arrow[r,draw=none,"\scriptstyle\sim" marking]& 
    B \arrow[l,shift left=0.75ex]\arrow[r,shift left=0.4ex]
    \arrow[r,draw=none,"\scriptscriptstyle\perp" marking]& 
    C \arrow[l,shift left=0.75ex]\\
 C \arrow[r,"\scriptscriptstyle\perp" {inner sep=0.1ex,rotate=180},
    "\scriptscriptstyle\perp"' {inner sep=0.1ex,rotate=180}] 
    \arrow[r,shift left=1.1ex] & 
    D \arrow[l,shift left=1.1ex] & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with bent arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[r,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex] \arrow[r,draw=none,"\sim" marking]& 
    B \arrow[l,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex]\arrow[r,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex]
    \arrow[r,draw=none,"\perp" marking]& 
    C \arrow[l,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex]\\
 C \arrow[r,"\perp" {inner sep=0.3ex,rotate=180},
    "\perp"' {inner sep=0.3ex,rotate=180}] 
    \arrow[r,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex] & 
    D \arrow[l,bend left=25,shift left=0.2ex] & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]